# Shiny fileInput used to selectInput

Tags: shiny

I am trying to get access to colnames(input$file1) for a selectInput drop down menu in a UI. In addition, I would like the default column that is selected to be the first numeric column. I'm not exactly how to accomplish this. It is beyond my shiny skill set. If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,
gwynn

```R
runApp(
 list(
   ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Use readxl"),
     tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Upload Data",
             sidebarPanel(
               helpText("Input an excel file here. We assume the data are in the 
                                  first sheet with the first row being headers."),
               br(),

               fileInput("file1", "Choose Excel File",
                         accept = c(
                           "xls",
                           "xlsx")
               ),
               br()
             )),
    ## This is where I get completely lost.
    tabPanel("General Inputs",
             selectInput("select", label = h3("Select column"), 
          choices = colnames(M()[[1]]), selected = M()[[2]][1])
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    M = reactive({
      M = taglist()
      inFile <- input$file1

      if(is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)
      file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                  paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
      D = read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
      D = as.data.frame(D)

      ## Upating file names
      colnames(D) <- labs <- gsub("\r\n"," ", colnames(D))
      nums = labs[which(sapply(D, is.numeric) == TRUE)]

      M[[1]] = D
      M[[2]] = nums
    })
   }
  )
 )
)
```

I asked this a few weeks ago and noone answered, in the meantime I fixed it:

```
 runApp(
 list(
   ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Use readxl"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Upload Data",
             sidebarPanel(
               helpText("Input an excel file here. We assume the data are in the 
                        first sheet with the first row being headers."),
               br(),

               fileInput("file1", "Choose Excel File",
                         accept = c(
                           "xls",
                           "xlsx")
               ),
               br(),

               actionButton("UI", "Add my data")
             )),

    tabPanel("General Inputs",
             uiOutput("VarsInput")
    )

  )),

server = function(input, output){
  M = reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    M = tagList()

    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
    D = read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
    D = as.data.frame(D)

    ## Upating file names
    colnames(D) <- labs <- gsub("\r\n"," ", colnames(D))
    nums = labs[which(sapply(D, is.numeric) == TRUE)]

    M[[1]] = D
    M[[2]] = nums

    M
  })

  output$VarsInput <- renderUI({
    selectInput("Choose a variable", "Variable to randomize:",
                choices = colnames(M()[[1]]), selected = M()[[2]][1])
  })

  }
 )
 )
```

Basically, I forgot to tell the reactive what to spit out, then I got lost b/c computers are stupid.

Comment: I fixed it! This works